# Error Failed to launch the browser process! WARNING: cannot start document portal: dial unix /run/user/0/bus: connect: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

i am using puppeter for pdf certificate and invoice. It was working fine in server. We had an issue in server and we needed to delete the tmp folder of the server. Now we are getting this error

```
    Error Failed to launch the browser process!
    2023/04/05 08:23:05.127967 cmd_run.go:1055: WARNING: cannot start document portal: dial unix /run/user/0/bus: connect: no such file or directory
    mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/0’: Permission denied
    /snap/chromium/2406/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 369: cannot create temp file for here-document: No such file or directory
    [0405/082307.461560:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(189)] Could not create NETLINK socket: Operation not permitted (1)
    [0405/082307.543446:WARNING:dns_config_service.cc(144)] Failed to read DnsHosts.
    [0405/082307.546564:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(214)] Creating shared memory in /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.Wvasql failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Here is the code

```
browser = await Puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: "/snap/bin/chromium",
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
  });
```

We re installed puppeter and chromium nothing seems working. Any idea what is wrong?